# tar extraction also automatically decompresses

Tags: tar

When I run

```
tar -cvzf archive.tgz file1 file2 ; rm file1 file2
```

it normally creates a compressed tarball, but how is it possible that

```
tar -xvf archive.tgz
```

gives me back the uncompressed files? I've always thought that the -z flag would be required.

Comment: Apparently, the creators of UNIX also think that that's how `tar` should behave:
http://9p.io/wiki/plan9/UNIX_to_Plan_9_command_translation/index.html

Comment: @PSkocik Sure, it breaks the unix philosophy: *Write programs that do one thing and do it well. Write programs to work together.*

Comment: @jlliagre I don't think so. Being able to infer that you need to gunzip when the file is gzipped doesn't imply your program must be monolithic.

Comment: @PSkocik You are right. At least GNU, Solaris and busybox tar implementations all use the external gzip utility so do not duplicate code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your `tar` implementation, likely the `GNU` one, is detecting the file passed as a parameter<sup>1</sup> is compressed.

The mostly used `tar` implementations these days, `GNU tar` and `busybox` ones, are looking to the first bytes of the file, a.k.a. magic number, to figure out if it is compressed and the compression algorithm to use.

The `tar` implementations found on commercial Unixes that are based on the original AT&T code do not support the `-z` flag in the first place. One notable exception is Solaris 11 `tar` where this extension has been added, including the ability to detect the file format.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>GNU tar doesn't detect if a file passed through stdin is compressed though, as already mentioned in another [reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253626/2594) and [SensorSmith's comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253596/tar-extraction-also-automatically-decompresses/253597?noredirect=1#comment1460453_253597).</sub>

Comment: I thought it looks at the suffix. It also has to know which compression method has been used to incompress. Would it do that correctly if the tar file was suffixed incorrectly?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, not rocket science, just look for file(1).

Comment: Actually, multiple tar implementations auto-detect whether the content is compressed.  A *good* answer would point this out, and how it is done.

Comment: @ThomasDickey go for it.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I didn't wrote other tar implementation never do, just that GNU tar being by far the most commonly used one these days, it was likely the one used by the OP. Note too that the original `tar` command (AT&T) didn't support `-z` in the first place.

Comment: @jlliagre I agree with you. As far as I remember, on HP-UX which is a System V based Unix, `tar` itself doesn't automatically uncompress gzip files. You have to do in two steps: tar followed by gzip

Comment: I remember a few years ago, some old versions of GNU tar (I am assuming from the system that it was a GNU one), needed the -z explicitely, even though a different system (with a more modern one), didn't. As a rule of thumb, if you know it is a tgz, provide the -z flag (eg. when providing instructions for others). If you know your locally installed verson auto-detects it, you _may_ skip it.

Comment: The edit didn't improve things.  When I commented, I made a to-do item to add to a page I've been writing on the general topic - ttyl

Comment: @Angel, That is correct. Automatically detecting compressed archived was added to GNU `tar` version 1.15 in December 2004.

Comment: FWIW, I believe the original reason for the auto-guessing came about as a result of the introduction of bzip compression (the -j flag). Uncompressing required you know what compression algorithm was used. And people often forgot and named bzip files as .tar.gz anyway. So you'd often do `tar xzf` which would fail then you'd try `tar xjf`. To make life easier why not let tar do the try-fail-try thing for you and just run `tar xf`?

Comment: @SensorSmith No need to downvote. Just add a comment explaining how the reply can be improved and why if you feel it needs to. The OP didn't mentioned using stdin with `tar` so imho that information was not mandatory, not to mention Jörg Schilling (†) already provided that piece of information in his reply.

Comment: Downvote removed as OP didn't mention stdin, but it is worth noting that GNU tar will fail to extract a compressed archive passed on stdin (unless the matching compression option is supplied).  It seems the authors prefer to tell a human what option they should have used rather than inefficiently buffer and copy both the buffer and the original pipe into the (de)compression utility.      Otherwise this is a great answer, especially given that the GNU tar man page still says that --auto-compress uses the file extension, but the file extension can be wrong and it will still work.

Comment: @SensorSmith Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Star introduced automated compression detection and automated decompression aprox. 20 years ago.

These days, some other tar implementations, like gtar copied the idea.

BTW: star understands the magic numbers in the compressed stream to detect the correct decompression method. Also note that gtar was reported to fail when a compressed archive is read from `stdin` instead from a named file.

Answer (score 2):

The `-z` option is not required in two well-known implementations of tar: GNU tar and BSD tar (aka [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/)).  Detecting the compression algorithm needed is trivial, done by inspecting the first few bytes of the input file.

Whether you happen to be using one or the other of those implementations largely depends upon which operating system you are using: Linux-based systems or BSD systems (including OSX).

I have summarized details of when these features were introduced on my page about [tar versus portability](http://invisible-island.net/autoconf/portability-tar.html#comp_compression).