# Can tar decompress an archive without untarring it?

Tags: tar, archive

If I have a compressed archive (e.g. `archive.tar.xz`), I can decompress it and get the archived files back with `tar xf archive.tar.xz`. As far as I understand, this is technically two steps: decompressing `archive.tar`, and then "splitting" (for want of a better word) `archive.tar` into the original file(s).

Is there a way to stop after decompressing, leaving `archive.tar`? In this case I could use `xz -d`, but I'd prefer to use `tar` since that doesn't tie me to `xz` specifically. `tar xf` seems to have (some) intelligence in determining what decompression to apply, which I'd like to keep.

So far, the best solution I can come up with is to `tar xf archive.tar.xz` followed by `tar cf [...]`.

Comment: ... after reviewing [another, similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253596/125869) question, I'm not confident that this is a real option - `tar` isn't really for decompression.

Answer (score 5):

As said in the comments, tar is for creating an archive. The additional compression options are a convenience. You can use the specific compression commands directly:

```
gzip, gunzip for .tar.gz
bzip2, bunzip2 for .tar.bz2
xz, unxz for .tar.xz
```

Answer (score 3):

`tar` itself doesn’t provide an option to decompress an archive without extracting its contents in some way: it manipulates archives, not their compression (in isolation).

There are decompression tools which support a variety of archive formats and will allow you to decompress an archive without knowing which specific compression tool was used; for example, with [the command-line version of The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/command-line):

```
unar -nr filename.tar.whatever
```

will extract `filename.tar`.